# How to fit b-spline regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, splines

> I want to create a function to estimate a time varying model with B splines such that:
>   $$ Y_i = \sum_{j=0}^p (B(T_i)X_{ij})^T \gamma_{0j} + \hat{\epsilon}_i$$
>   on an equally spaced B-spline basis $B(x) = (B_1(x),...,B_L(x))^T$ on $[0,1]$ where $L=c_Ln^{1/5}$ and the degree of the basis is **at least 2**.

I didn't understand the meaning of $L$ here, how is this implemented, it seems $\gamma_{0j} \in \mathbb{R}^L$ and $B(T_i)X_{ij} \in \mathbb R{}^L$.  Could someone verify this code?

```
#Simulated Data.. (time varying model)
  n = 200
  X <- matrix(rnorm(1000*n),nrow = n)
  U <- matrix(runif(2*n),nrow = n)
  T <- tcrossprod(U,t(c(0,1)))
  epsilon <- rnorm(n,0,1)
  Y <- 2*X[,1] + 3*T*X[,2] + X[,3]*(T+1)^2+ 4*X[,4]*sin(2*pi*T)/(2-sin(2*pi*T))+1*epsilon

#library(splines2)
L = n^(1/5) 
bsMat <<- bSpline(X, degree = 2, intercept = TRUE)
```

This isn't right because the spline matrix is of dimension 200000x3... where X is a 200x 1000 matrix (so clearly it has multiplied the rows and columns of X to get bsMat dimension). This therefore gives gives non-conformable arguments when i apply a time varying regression:

```
library(tvReg)
tvm =  tvLM(Y ~ bsMat)
```

Comment: uncomformable, not uncomfortable?

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate your model using `lm()` function. The fact is that your model matrix is not correctly defined. To make it clearer I will use a simpler example. You will then be able to extend the reasoning to your additive structure (you might want to give a look to the `mgcv` package). I will consider the model:
$$
y = x(t) f(t) + \epsilon
$$
with $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma_{\epsilon})$ and $x(t)$ is the (observed/predictor) variable with which you would like to "interact" your smooth effect $f(t)$. The model can be re-written as
$$
y = \mbox{diag}(x) B \alpha + \epsilon
$$
where $B \alpha$ is the B-spline approximation of $f(t)$. To make a concrete example, we can simulate some data as follows:
$$
y = 0.2 + 2 \sin(t) * x(t) + \epsilon
$$
where, $x(t)$ will be $\cos(t/2)$.
Below you will find a small R-code. I will use the `splineDesign()` function in the `splines` package to compute the B-spline matrix on equally spaced internal knots. I left some comments in the code. I hope it is clear enough and helps for the original question.

```
set.seed(2015)
library(splines)

# Simulated Data.. (time varying model)
N      = 200
time   = seq(0, 2 * pi, len = N)
sd_sim = 0.1
xt     = cos(time/2)
eps    = rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = sd_sim)
ft     = 2 * sin(time) 
y      = 0.2 + ft * xt + eps 

# Create B-splines
deg   = 3
ndx   = deg * N^(1/5) 
xr    = max(time)
xl    = min(time)
xmax  = xr + 0.01 * (xr - xl)
xmin  = xl - 0.01 * (xr - xl)
dt    = (xmax - xmin) / ndx
knots = seq(xmin - deg * dt, xmax + deg * dt, by = dt)
B     = splineDesign(knots = knots, x = time, ord = deg + 1, derivs = 0,outer.ok = TRUE)

# Create model matrix
X  = diag(xt)
Mm = X %*% B

# Fit model
fit = lsfit(Mm, y, intercept = T)

# Plot results - yhat, f(t)
par(mfrow = c(2, 1), mar = c(3,3,3,3))
plot(time, y, main = 'Data and fit')
lines(time, cbind(1, Mm) %*% fit$coefficients, col = 2)

plot(time, ft, main = 'Time-varying component', ylim = c(2.5, -2.5))
lines(time, B %*% fit$coefficients[-1], col = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how you want to construct your spline basis matrix, but normally you can use 1 variable, and construct a matrix for its $x,x^2,x^3$ terms.. And you add this for each term.

In your code:

```
bSpline(X, degree = 2, intercept = TRUE)
```

You get 200000x3 because `X` is treated 1 variable, the matrix is used as a vector and you get a matrix the length of your matrix X.. If you want a spline basis for each of your columns in X, you can do:

```
bsMat = lapply(1:ncol(X),function(i)bSpline(X[,i],degree=2,intercept=TRUE))
bsMat = do.call(cbind,bsMat)
```

You have now 3000 columns, and you can't fit this with a linear model and I am not so sure if this is actually what you intend. You can check this [summary](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-019-0666-3) about how splines are used, and maybe redefine you questions.

If the spline is only intended for a few columns, then use the code above to do lapply( ..), join it with your other predictors and regress.